# Crontab Output problem

Tags: cron, crontab

I have this script.  When I run it from the command line, it works fine.  When I run it from cron, it only prints out half of the data

The results should look like this:

```
07/Feb/2012 11 0.5

07/Feb/2012 11  0.333333

07/Feb/2012 11  0.3
```

currently I'm getting just the date data when I run it from cron:

```
07/Feb/2012 11 
07/Feb/2012 11  
07/Feb/2012 11  
07/Feb/2012 11
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
PATH=/opt/someApp/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/awk

# Generate data and hour stamp
date '+%d/%b/%Y %H' > /var/www/stats/datedata

#Crank out  and consider utlisation
/usr/bin/./top -d 3 -n3 | /bin/./grep "Cpu" | awk '{ sum += $2/3 } END { print sum }' > /var/www/stats/usage_cpu

#
/usr/bin/./paste /var/www/stats/datedata /var/www/stats/usage_cpu >> /var/www/stats/thedata
```

This is my crontab entry:
(I'm using /etc/crontab to set this up)

```
20 *    * * *   root    /var/www/stats/./stats.sh
```

Comment: The question you are asking seems to be semi ambiguous... are you asking "How can I get the cronscript to return the output in the format that I want?"

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is that the script works ok when I run it, but when cron runs the script it does not do the processing of the top awk line thus giving me only 2 coloums of data (the date related stuff) not the date and Cron awk stuff

Comment: I get what you're explaining, but I didn't understand the question being asked, because I didnt see any specific question within your post.  Given your explanation, though, the question is "How can I get the crontab to display the output correctly?".

Comment: For some reason crontab is not letting me generate data from either awk grep or top - I have opened up permissions on all files that the script writes to - have added I think enough path info.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `/usr/bin/awk` instead of just `awk`.